# ES6 Koa.js run generator function to completion and return asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-6, koa

Using koa.js, I want to make an API which runs a generator function that runs a long time in the background, but sends a token back to the user immediately.

The user can then use that token to retrieve status of their job later.

```
'use strict';
var generateToken = function(){
    //...
};

var processData = function *(data, token) {
    //...
    var a = yield analysis(data);
    console.log(a) // a is undefined
};

app.post('/process_data', validate, function *(next) {
    var token = generateToken();
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (var i of processData(that.request.body, token)){
            continue;
        }
    });
    this.body = "this should return immediately " + token;
    return next;
});
```

Running it within the setTimeout, variable 'a' is not saved. How do I construct this so that processData runs exactly like a normal yield?

Comment: I think you'll want to use [co](https://github.com/tj/co) directly

Answer (score 3):

You would probably want to have the long running process get handled by a job queue such as [Kue](https://github.com/learnboost/kue)

You would queue the job with a http post

then check on the job with a http get

Here is a rough outline of what I think you want to be doing:

```
var kue       = require('kue'),
    koa       = require('koa'),
    route     = require('koa-router'),
    thunkify  = require('thunkify'),
    parse     = require('co-body'),
    co        = require('co'),
    app       = koa(),
    jobs      = kue.createQueue();

app.use(route(app));

// turn callbacks into thunks for generators
var createJob = thunkify(jobs.create);
var findJob   = thunkify(kue.Job.get);

// Process the job here
jobs.process('longProcess', function(job, done){
    // do work in here
    // call done(err) when completed
    // EDIT: if you want to handle job using generators/yield
    // you could use a library like co
    co(function *(){
        var qs = yield doWork(job.data); 
        done();
      }).error(done);
});

// Queue/Start the Job here
app.post('/jobs', function *(){
  var body = yield parse(this);
  var job = yield createJob('longProcess', body);
  this.body = job.id;
});

// Check Status of job here
app.get('/jobs/:token', function *(){
  var job = yield findJob(this.params.token);
  this.body = job;
  // job.status === 'complete' || ...
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: What if you wanted to yield to another process inside of the jobs.process callback? How would you go about that?

Comment: Do you mean using a generator/yield etc?

Comment: yes, how can i yield to a generator and then send back the result of what the generator returns for example:

`var jobs = kue.createQueue();

jobs.process('questions', function (job, done){
    var gen = questions(job.data);
    var a = gen.next();
    job.send(a);
    done();
});

function *questions(data) {
    var qs = yield* processQuestions(data);
}`
Where processQuestions is another generator

Comment: You could use a generator flow control library like `co` which is what koa uses.  See the edited answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bergi for the solution.

```
app.post('/process_data', validate, function *(next) {
    var token = generateToken();

    co(processData(this.request.body, token));

    this.body = "this should return immediately " + token;
    return next;
});
```

Comment: Afaik you may simplify to `co(processData(this.request.body, token))`. No need for the anonymous generator expression.